# In perl, how do you store multiple values from a single test file line into an array

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, store

Here are a couple of typical lines from an input file I am trying to crunch:

```
ICC2_DPD  2.7V  ma  0.006 0.006 0.006  ... ... 
DPD_Rel   2.7V  ma  0.062 0.054 0.040 0.065 0.037 0.066 0.071 0.073 ... ... ...
```

(The number of floats can vary) Here is what I initially started with:

```
if(/^(\w+)\s+(\d+\.?\d*)V\s+(\w+)/) 
{
    print $OUT "$1 $2 $3\n";
}
```

How would you capture and store the floating point values into an array/hash given that the number of values varies.  I am stuck on how to manage the termination of the array.

Comment: You ought to check out `push`, `pop`, [`shift`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift.html) and `unshift`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, in your case, I would probably consider using [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html), separating the fields on whitespace:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    my @vals = split;   # default split is fine
    print join(" ", @vals[3 .. $#vals]), "\n";
}
```

Or if you want to store them, just push them onto an array, or use a hash with a suitable key. Something like...

```
push @array,      [ @vals[3 .. $#vals] ];  # push an array ref
$hash{$vals[0]} = [ @vals[3 .. $#vals] ];  # use a hash
```

The `[ ... ]` part is creating an anonymous array ref, which can then store the line's values in a single scalar slot.

Comment: So why not use `Text::CSV` in this case?

Comment: He did not specify that it was a csv file. If it is, you could use it.

Comment: In my experience, when people say they have a CSV file it is to be taken with a pinch of salt :) The data in the other question, when you recommended using a module, looked very much like this. That is why I am confused over your different approach.

Comment: Yes, sometimes people say things which are not necessarily true, but the basic premise must be that if parsing CSV is asked for, parsing CSV is how its handled. If nothing else, for other people reading the question afterwards. Mind you, in that particular case, a CSV parser was not strictly required, but data and/or users may vary over time.

Comment: Yeah I think I almost buy that! +1 anyway :)

Comment: Thank you. You should buy it. I have a full refund policy within 30 days, no questions asked. I can also confess to a certain fondness for the Text::CSV module, which makes me use it whenever I can.

Comment: You could use `my ($key, $v, $ma, @vals) = split;`

Answer (score 0):

I might be inclined to write something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::Util qw( sum );

my @data;

while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my ($state, $voltage, $current_unit, $obs) = split ' ', $line, 4;
    my @obs = ($obs =~ / ( [0-9] [.] [0-9]+ )/gx);
    push @data, {
        state => $state,
        voltage => $voltage,
        current_unit => $current_unit,
        obs => \@obs,
        average_current => sum(@obs) / @obs,
    };
}

for my $x (@data) {
    printf(
        "State = %-16sAverage current = %.3f%s\n",
        @$x{qw(state average_current current_unit)},
    );
}

__DATA__
ICC2_DPD  2.7V  ma  0.006 0.006 0.006
DPD_Rel   2.7V  ma  0.062 0.054 0.040 0.065 0.037 0.066 0.071 0.073
```

Output:

```
State = ICC2_DPD        Average current = 0.006ma
State = DPD_Rel         Average current = 0.059ma
```